# Content hierarchical URLs with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, dynamic, ember.js, routes, prototype

### Question

*How do I manage routing within Ember.js that supports URLs describing content, not data architecture?*

### Details

I've been trying to set up a simple Ember.js app to allow me to create prototypes to test Information Architecture quickly. The idea is to have a set of pages in a JS object, and the render those pages in their hierarchy with Ember.js.

For instance, I have a content page that lives as a child to a navigation page. The URL then becomes `#/navigation_id/article_id/`. In the data object, the pages live on the same level, to allow a page to "live" in two different places at the same time. So an article with the ID `GreatArticle` might live both in the navigation `ContentNavigation` and in the blog `MyBlog`so both these URLs would be true - `#/ContentNavigation/GreatArticle` and `#/MyBlog/GreatArticle`. The page would render the same, except for the breadcrumb.

### Code

Right now I'm looping through page object and creating my routes dynamically:

#### data.js

```
// Page data
// Page types - magazine, navigation, article, calendar, search
var pages = [
    {
        id: 'magazine',
        type: 'magazine',
        title: 'My Magazine',
        subtitle: 'September 2014',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod dignissim ante sed laoreet. Morbi ullamcorper cursus sapien, in mollis arcu viverra eu.',
        children: []
    },
    {
        id: 'search',
        type: 'search',
        title: 'search',
    },
    {
        id: 'about',
        type: 'navigation',
        title: 'Info',
        children: [
            'education'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'education',
        type: 'navigation',
        title: 'Get  an education',
        content: 'Facts',
        children: [
            'bachelor',
            'masters'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'bachelor',
        type: 'article',
        title: 'Bachelor',
        content: 'Bachelor'
    },
    {
        id: 'masters',
        type: 'article',
        title: 'Masters',
        content: 'Masters'
    }
];
```

#### app.js

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

// Routing
function mapRoutes (pages, scope, path) {
    path = path || '';
    $.each(pages, function (index, id) {
        var page = data.pages.findBy('id', id),
        pagePath = path + '/' + id;
        if (!page || page.type === 'shortcut' || page.hasRoute) {

        } else {
            scope.resource(page.type, { path: '/' + id }, function () {
                if (page.children && page.children.length) {
                    mapRoutes(page.children, this, pagePath);
                }
            });
            page.hasRoute = pagePath;
            console.log(pagePath)
        }
    });
}
App.Router.map(function () {
    mapRoutes(data.app.menu, this);
});
App.NavigationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('NavigationRoute.model');
        return {};
    }
});
App.MagazineRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('MagazineRoute.model');
        return {};
    }
});
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('ArticleRoute.model');
        return {};
    }
});
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('SearchRoute.model');
        return {};
    }
});
App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log('CalendarRoute.model');
        return {};
    }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var menu = [];

        $.each(data.app.menu, function (index, item) {
            if (data.pages[item]) {
                menu.push(data.pages[item]);
            }
        });

        return {
            title: data.app.title,
            menu: menu
        };
    }
});
```

### The problem

Right now the code creates all my routes as it should (/magazine, /about/uddannelse/bachelor, /about/uddannelse/kandidat, /about/uddannelse, /about, /search), but I have two problems:

- When navigating to nested pages, all parent routes and templates are called. So navigating to `/about/uddannelse/kandidat` outputs this in the console:

  ```
  NavigationRoute.model 
  NavigationRoute.model 
  ArticleRoute.model
  ```

  and it also renders the `navigation.hbs` template - not the `article.hbs` template as I would expect.
- The routes have no idea what data are hooked up to them, as I'm not using any of Ember.js `:id` dynamic route functionality. I would love to use that, but nesting that has resulted in even worse errors.

### Summary

*How do I create dynamic routes with Ember.js in a way so that the URL and the App itself reflect the content hierarchy?*

**I really hope you can help me :)**

### Addendum

I had [this conversation with Gabor Babicz](https://twitter.com/xeppelin/status/423191196962672640) ([@xeppelin](http://twitter.com/xeppelin)) on the 14th, which might be helpful for others. Two diagrams came from that:

- [App hierarchy / IA](http://cl.ly/image/3v3Q3L3M0008)
- [Content flow](http://cl.ly/image/2n3k3a3K1U19)